# VMware Player in startup

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, vmware-player

We have a windows 2008, We have installed VMWARE player. How do I put VMWARE Player in start up? Please help me..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you're using inappropriate technology. Player is intended for workstation use and is not designed to be run at system startup. That doesn't mean it can't be achieved, just that you will have work around inherent problems. Why not use VMWare Server instead?

Comment: Sorry, Its not a server its a workstation.

Comment: Windows 2008 is server software. What are you really trying to accomplish? There may be better ways...

Comment: What workstation OS are you using then?  You have the question tagged as win2k8 server.  Please edit your question and add in as much information about what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

This is really an easy Google search:
http://google.com/search?q=vmware+server+power+on+on+startup